# PDFBox: Convert PDF to Image is slower than expected

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, pdfbox

I am currently using this code to convert a pdf to an image:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Image convertPDFtoImage(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {

    Image convertedImage = null;

    try {

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(bais);
        List<PDPage> list = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage page = list.get(0);

        BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 64);
        convertedImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);

        document.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertedImage;
}
```

Then, I show the convertedImage in an JavaFX ImageView.

Further, I need to import these two packages, while I am not using them:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser;
```

Two questions:

- **Does it normally take two to three seconds to convert a simple one page PDF to Image where the DPI is set on 64 (which is not that high in my opinion)?** It seems to be a bit slow.
- **Why do I need those two imports while I am not using them?** If I don't import them, I get a lot of errors and the conversion does not work.

I would like to show a PDF quickly in JavaFX, and two to three seconds is just too long. Any other ways of showing a PDF in JavaFX (other than convert it to an image) are very welcome.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Regarding the imports required: If the parser and logger use dynamic ways to search for implementation classes by name, they will only be able to find them if they are initialized. That will happen if you import the classes, causing static initializers to be executed.... just a guess...

Comment: Importing something doesn't cause code to be executed; it is just a compile-time namespace convenience.

Comment: While it is true that higher dpi means slower execution, the time needed to render a PDF also depends of the complexity of the PDF itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. I also had similar problem while converting pdf into images, I solved this by upgrading PDFBox from 1.8 to 2.0. 
   This improved my performance by 50%. Previously my app is taking around 10 seconds to convert pdf into images and now it is taking 5 seconds.
   Please use following link as reference while upgrading PDFBox -
   https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html
2. Additional imports are not required for PDFBox.

Regards,
Yogesh